# Show the Steps Taken to Solve an Equation

Tags: equations

I am new to LaTex and I am trying to type a document where I show the steps I took to solve an equation however I do not know how to do this in LaTex. I am trying to display something like this:

```
 x^2+2x+1 = 0  
 (x+1)^2 = 0  
 x = -1
```

Is there a way to do this (or something similar) in LaTex? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should consider using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  x^2 + 2x + 1 &= 0 \\
  (x+1)^2 &= 0 \\
  \llap{$\rightarrow$\hspace{50pt}} x &= -1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\implies` would be a better then using `\rightarrow`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really neat package called `witharrows` that does a really nice job of what you're trying to do.  It creates an environment called `WithArrows` that takes the place of `aligned`.  There are several tweaks you can use to adjust the spacing, color, and types of arrows used to describe the steps.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{witharrows}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \begin{document}
        
    \begin{equation}
    \setlength{\jot}{10pt}
    \begin{WithArrows}
    ax^2 + bx + c & = 0 \Arrow[xoffset=-2cm]{Multiply both sides by $4a$} \\
    4a^2 x^2 + 4abx + 4ac & = 0 \Arrow[xoffset=-1cm]{Subtract $4ac$} \\
    4a^2 x^2 + 4abx & = - 4ac \\
    4a^2 x^2 + 4abx + b^2 & = b^2 - 4ac \\
    (2ax + b)^2 & = b^2 - 4ac \\
    2ax + b & = \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \\
    2ax & = -b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}
    \end{WithArrows}
    \nonumber
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
 x^2+2x+1 &=& 0      \nonumber \\
 (x+1)^2  &=& 0 \nonumber \\
  x & = & -1
\end{eqnarray}
```

You might want to number each step by removing the `\nonumber` commands; I only numbered the last one.

More examples [here](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/cookbook.html).

Comment: `eqnarray` should never be used, see e.g. [\eqnarray vs \align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.

Comment: There we go! Guess my Latex-Fu is outdated, thanks for the heads up!