# Showing how to solve an equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, rules

Is there a package that would allow me to draw a horizontal line in math mode, 
like what is suggested below?

```
\begin{align*}
x + 2 &= 3\\ % First equation
 -2 &= -2\\  % Second equation
%% Horizontal line drawn under last equation HERE, with line as wide as 
%% first equation
x &= 1
\end{align*}
```

Comment: 99.9% duplicate: [Show the steps taken to solve an equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54493/5764)

Comment: Besides to perfect answers bellow, I encourage you to put your solutions in a proof environment. See this question: [How to correctly format (and align) a LaTeX proof?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27283/how-to-correctly-format-and-align-a-latex-proof)

Comment: @Werner - Would you consider the part about drawing a rule that spans the alignment directive ( `&` ) to fall into the remaining 0.1%? :-)

Comment: @Mico: Looking at egreg's answer... yes.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment and takes care to preserve the appropriate amounts of spacing around operators of type mathbin ("+" and "-") and mathrel ("="). It also uses the macro `\midrule` (from the `booktabs` package) to get nice spacing around the horizontal line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ @{} r @{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{} r @{{}={}} r @{} }
x & + &  2 &  3\\
  & - &  2 & -2\\
\midrule
  &  &   x &  1\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Easy enough: use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x + 2 &= 3\\ % First equation
 -2 &= -2\\  % Second equation
\hline
x &= 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Better yet, use also `booktabs` and `\midrule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x + 2 &= 3\\ % First equation
 -2 &= -2\\  % Second equation
\midrule
x &= 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}@{\,}>{$=}l<{$}}
x + 2 & 3  \\
   -2 & -2 \\ \hline
    x & 1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are two solutions using `IEEEtrantools`:

### Embed `IEEEeqnarraybox` inside `equation`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{rCr}
              x + 2 &=&  3
    \\          - 2 &=& -2
    \\ \hline
    \\            x &=&  1  
  \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

For a better control I recommend to use `IEEEeqnarray`.

### Using `IEEEeqnarray`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCr}
                               x + 2 &=&  3
  \\                             - 2 &=& -2
  \\*[-1.0\normalbaselineskip] \cmidrule{1-3}
  \\*[-1.5\normalbaselineskip]     x &=&  1
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Stefan Moser wrote an [excellent tutorial](http://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) on `IEEEtrantools`.